# Can't open PDF after downloading it from Firebase

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, pdf-viewer

I'm using this code to download and show a PDF in an activity. It's downloaded successfully but not opened when the download is completed.

```
public class PdfView extends AppCompatActivity {
    private PDFView pdfView;
    private TextView textView;
    private String pdfName = "";
    private String pdfUrl = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(pdf_activity);

   pdfView = findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
    pValue = findViewById(R.id.pValue);
    down =findViewById(R.id.down);

        if(getIntent().getExtras() != null){
            pdfName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("pdf_name");
            pdfUrl = getIntent().getExtras().getString("pdf_url");

            if(pdfName != null)
                pdfName = pdfName.replace("", "")+".pdf";
            downloadFile();
        }
    }

    private void downloadFile() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean>(){
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                return downloadFile();
            }

            @Nullable
            private Boolean downloadFile(){
                try {
                    File file = getFileStreamPath(pdfName);
                    if(file.exists())return true;
                    try {
                        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream =
                                openFileOutput(pdfName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        URL u = new URL(pdfUrl);
                        URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
                        int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();
                        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(u.openStream());
                        byte data[] = new byte[contentLength];
                        long total =0;
                        int count;
                        while((count = input.read(data)) != -1){
                            total+= count;
                            publishProgress((int)((total * 100) / contentLength));
                            fileOutputStream.write(data,0,count);
                        }
                        fileOutputStream.flush();
                        fileOutputStream.close();
                        input.close();
                        return true;
                    } catch (final Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return false;
                    }
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean){
                if (aBoolean){
                    openPdf(pdfName);
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(PdfView.this, "unable to download ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }.execute();
    }
    private void openPdf(String pdfName) {
        try {
            final File file = getFileStreamPath(pdfName);
            if (file != null){
                Log.e("file","file"+file.getAbsolutePath());
                pdfView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pdfView.fromFile(file).enableSwipe(true).swipeHorizontal(false).onError(new OnErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable t) {
                        Log.e("file", "file" + t.toString());
                        try {
                            if (file.exists())
                                file.delete();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).enableAntialiasing(true).spacing(2).pageFitPolicy(FitPolicy.WIDTH).load();

            }

        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Adapter Class

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {
MainActivity mainActivity;
ArrayList<DownModel> downModels;

public MyAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, ArrayList<DownModel> downModels) {
    this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    this.downModels = downModels;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mainActivity.getBaseContext());
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.elements, viewGroup, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int i) {

    myViewHolder.mName.setText(downModels.get(i).getName());
    myViewHolder.mLink.setText(downModels.get(i).getLink());
    myViewHolder.mDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(myViewHolder.mDownload.getContext(),PdfView.class);

            intent.putExtra("pdf_url", downModels.get(i).getLink());
            intent.putExtra("pdf_name",downModels.get(i).getName());
            myViewHolder.mDownload.getContext().startActivity(intent);

        }
    });




}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return downModels.size();
}
}
```

> 2020-02-19 23:08:35.130 1919-1919/com.solutions.rsaggarwal I/Timeline:
>   Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:163047167
>
> 2020-02-19 23:08:35.173 1919-1919/com.solutions.rsaggarwal
>   W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token
>   android.os.BinderProxy@281d3b6
>
> 2020-02-19 23:08:35.250 1919-1919/com.solutions.rsaggarwal
>   D/com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfiumCore: Starting PdfiumAndroid 1.9.0
>
> 2020-02-19 23:08:35.317 1919-1919/com.solutions.rsaggarwal E/file:
>   file/data/user/0/com.solutions.rsaggarwal/files/Chapter 1: Organic
>   Chemistry.pdf
>
> 2020-02-19 23:08:35.317 1919-1919/com.solutions.rsaggarwal
>   W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke
>   virtual method 'void
>   com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView.setVisibility(int)' on a null
>   object reference
>
> 2020-02-19 23:08:35.317 1919-1919/com.solutions.rsaggarwal
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.solutions.rsaggarwal.PdfView.openPdf(PdfView.java:116)
>
> 2020-02-19 23:08:35.317 1919-1919/com.solutions.rsaggarwal
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.solutions.rsaggarwal.PdfView.access$200(PdfView.java:27)
>
> 2020-02-19 23:08:35.317 1919-1919/com.solutions.rsaggarwal
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.solutions.rsaggarwal.PdfView$1.onPostExecute(PdfView.java:104)
>
> 2020-02-19 23:08:35.317 1919-1919/com.solutions.rsaggarwal
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.solutions.rsaggarwal.PdfView$1.onPostExecute(PdfView.java:52)
>
> 2020-02-19 23:08:35.317 1919-1919/com.solutions.rsaggarwal
>   W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:695)
>
> 2020-02-19 23:08:35.317 1919-1919/com.solutions.rsaggarwal
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:180)
>
> 2020-02-19 23:08:35.317 1919-1919/com.solutions.rsaggarwal
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:712)
>
> 2020-02-19 23:08:35.317 1919-1919/com.solutions.rsaggarwal
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>
> 2020-02-19 23:08:35.317 1919-1919/com.solutions.rsaggarwal
>   W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
>
> 2020-02-19 23:08:35.317 1919-1919/com.solutions.rsaggarwal
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6823)
>
> 2020-02-19 23:08:35.317 1919-1919/com.solutions.rsaggarwal
>   W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>
> 2020-02-19 23:08:35.317 1919-1919/com.solutions.rsaggarwal
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
>
> 2020-02-19 23:08:35.317 1919-1919/com.solutions.rsaggarwal
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
>
> 2020-02-19 23:08:39.223 1919-1995/com.solutions.rsaggarwal
>   I/ions.rsaggarwa: ProcessProfilingInfo new_methods=5526 is saved
>   saved_to_disk=1 resolve_classes_delay=8000

Comment: Obviously the problem is in the pdfView. It will be better if you add code from this component.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't assign the id of pdfview so it's unable to open the pdf.   Is it possible to store pdf in internal storage, so it can't be accessed by other apps?